# How to load a Bitmap with Picasso without using an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso, android-bitmap

With `ImageView`, I can use the following code to download image with callback

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(url).into(imageView, new Callback()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() 
    {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() { }
);
```

Or simply get the Bitmap from this `Picasso.with(activity).load(url).get();`. Is there anyway to add callback for just download the image? If possible please provide sample code, Cheers!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can **create a** `Target` and then modify the `Bitmap` inside the Targets callback method `onBitmapLoaded(...)`. Here is how:

```
// make sure to set Target as strong reference
private Target loadtarget;

public void loadBitmap(String url) {

    if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            // do something with the Bitmap
            handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed() {

        }
    };

    Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(loadtarget);
}

public void handleLoadedBitmap(Bitmap b) {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: Complier complains about adding `final` to the `myLoadedBitmap`, but I can't assign it obviously, is it possible to fix?

Comment: As I am trying to share to Instagram, it is ok to share from local drawable but not from URL. Figuring out..

Comment: I noticed that `onBitmapLoaded` won't call after `onPrepareLoad` http://i.imgur.com/kKdba3d.png

Comment: Make sure to set Target as strong reference, works like a charm! thank you

Comment: what is it going to be the value of String url ?

Comment: @MedAL That should be the url of image.